# How to prompt user for geolocation using xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am working on a app in xamarin forms app that needs ask for the geolocation permission and if granted it needs to get the geolocation data from the device and then put the geolocation coordinates into the forecast.io URL I am using the Geolocator plugin by James Montemagno as well as the PermissionsPlugin by James Montemagno when I open the radar page the screen just stays white it never ask's for my permission here's my xamarin forms code:

```
using AppName.Data;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Plugin.Geolocator;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Plugin.Permissions;
using Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions;
using System;

namespace AppName.Radar
{
    public partial class RadarHome : ContentPage
    {
        public RadarHome()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

         async void locator()
        {
            try
            {
                var status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Location);
                if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
                {
                    if (await CrossPermissions.Current.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationaleAsync(Permission.Location))
                    {
                        await DisplayAlert("Need location", "Gunna need that location", "OK");
                    }

                    var results = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(Permission.Location);
                    status = results[Permission.Location];
                }

                if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
                {
                    var browser = new WebView();
                    var results = await CrossGeolocator.Current.GetPositionAsync(10000);
                    browser.Source  = "https://forecast.io/?mobile=1#/f/" + "Lat: " + results.Latitude + " Long: " + results.Longitude;
                }
                else if (status != PermissionStatus.Unknown)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Location Denied", "Can not continue, try again.", "OK");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Location Denied", "Can not continue, try again.", "OK");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here's my Android MainActivity code:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using Android;
using Plugin.Permissions;

namespace AppName.Droid
{
    [Activity(MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation, Theme = "@style/CustomTheme")]

    public class MainActivity : FormsApplicationActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }

        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            PermissionsImplementation.Current.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```

Am I leaving something out? both plugins are installed in both the forms project the android project and the iOS project

Comment: RadarHome never calls locator().

Comment: similar code same problem.  the crossgeolocator doesn't prompt for user permission

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48487333/location-permission-for-android-above-6-0-with-xamarin-forms-maps?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the required permissions.

In **Android**, to allow our application to access location services, we need to enable two Android permissions: `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`.

In **iOS**, Depending on if you will be always using geolocation (such as a maps app), or just at certain points in a user’s workflow, you will either need to add the key `NSLocationWhenInUsageDescription` or `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` in your `Info.plist`, along with a new string entry for the key that describes exactly what you’ll be doing with the user’s location. When the permission is prompted to the user at runtime, the description listed here will display.

In Windows, the `ID_CAP_LOCATION` permission must be enabled.

Read the full blog about it here - [Geolocation for iOS, Android, and Windows Made Easy](https://blog.xamarin.com/geolocation-for-ios-android-and-windows-made-easy/)

Comment: The required permissions have already been added to the android manifest and info.plist was updated with NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription prior to asking this question any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Xamarin Interface

```
    public interface MyLocationTracker
   {
            void ObtainMyLocation();
         event EventHandler<MyLocationEventArgs> locationObtained;

      }

public interface MyLocationEventArgs
  {
    double lat { get; set; }
    double lng { get; set; }
   }
```

---

### 2. Android Dependency Code

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(GetMyLocationStatus))]
namespace BarberApp.Droid
{
public class GetMyLocationStatus: Java.Lang.Object,MyLocationTracker,ILocationListener
{


    private LocationManager _locationManager;
    private string _locationProvider;
    private Location _currentLocation { get; set; }

    public GetMyLocationStatus() {

    this.InitializeLocationManager();

    }
    public event EventHandler<MyLocationEventArgs> locationObtained;

    event EventHandler<MyLocationEventArgs> MyLocationTracker.locationObtained
    {
        add
        {
            locationObtained += value;

        }

        remove
        {
            locationObtained -= value;

        }
    }




    void InitializeLocationManager()
    {
        _locationManager = (LocationManager)Forms.Context.GetSystemService(Context.LocationService);
    }


    public void OnLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        _currentLocation = location;

        if (location != null)
        {
            LocationEventArgs args = new LocationEventArgs();
            args.lat = location.Latitude;
            args.lng = location.Longitude;

            locationObtained(this, args);



        }


    }



    void MyLocationTracker.ObtainMyLocation()
    {
        _locationManager = (LocationManager)Forms.Context.GetSystemService(Context.LocationService);

        if (!_locationManager.IsProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GpsProvider) || !_locationManager.IsProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NetworkProvider))
        {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Forms.Context);
            builder.SetTitle("Location service not active");
            builder.SetMessage("Please Enable Location Service and GPS");
            builder.SetPositiveButton("Activate", (object sender, DialogClickEventArgs e) =>
            {



                    Intent intent = new Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionLocationSourceSettings);
                    Forms.Context.StartActivity(intent);




            });

            Dialog alertDailog = builder.Create();

            alertDailog.SetCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            alertDailog.Show();
        }

        else {

            _locationManager.RequestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NetworkProvider,
                    0,   //---time in ms---
                    0,   //---distance in metres---
                    this);
        }



    }


    ~GetMyLocationStatus(){
        _locationManager.RemoveUpdates(this);
    }

}


public class LocationEventArgs : EventArgs, MyLocationEventArgs
{
    public double lat { get; set; }
    public double lng { get; set; }
}
}
```

---

### 3. IOS Dependency Code

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(GetILocationStatus))]
namespace BarberApp.iOS
{


public class GetILocationStatus : MyLocationTracker
{


    public GetILocationStatus() { }

    CLLocationManager lm;

    public event EventHandler<MyLocationEventArgs> locationObtained;
     event EventHandler<MyLocationEventArgs> MyLocationTracker.locationObtained
    {
        add
        {
            locationObtained += value;

        }

        remove
        {
            locationObtained -= value;

        }
    }

void MyLocationTracker.ObtainMyLocation()
    {

        lm = new CLLocationManager();
        lm.DesiredAccuracy = CLLocation.AccuracyBest;
        lm.DistanceFilter = CLLocationDistance.FilterNone;

        lm.LocationsUpdated +=
            (object sender, CLLocationsUpdatedEventArgs e) =>
            {
                var locations = e.Locations;
                var strLocation =
                    locations[locations.Length - 1].
                        Coordinate.Latitude.ToString();
                strLocation = strLocation + "," +
                    locations[locations.Length - 1].
                        Coordinate.Longitude.ToString();
                LocationEventArgs args = new LocationEventArgs();
                args.lat = locations[locations.Length - 1].
                    Coordinate.Latitude;
                args.lng = locations[locations.Length - 1].
                    Coordinate.Longitude;
                locationObtained(this, args);
            };

        lm.AuthorizationChanged += (object sender,
            CLAuthorizationChangedEventArgs e) =>
        {
            if (e.Status ==
                CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse)
            {
                lm.StartUpdatingLocation();
            }
        };
        lm.RequestWhenInUseAuthorization();

    }

    ~GetILocationStatus()
    {
        lm.StopUpdatingLocation();
    }


}



public class LocationEventArgs : EventArgs, MyLocationEventArgs
{
    public double lat { get; set; }
    public double lng { get; set; }
}
}
```

---

### 4. Xamarin Forms Code

```
MyLocationTracker msi;


    double BetaLat;
    double BetaLog;

            var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;

            if (locator.IsGeolocationEnabled == false)
            {

                if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Android)
                {


                    msi = DependencyService.Get<MyLocationTracker>();
                    msi.locationObtained += (object Esender, MyLocationEventArgs ew) => {
                        Console.WriteLine(ew.lat);
                    };
                    msi.ObtainMyLocation();


                }

                else if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.iOS)
                {
                    msi = DependencyService.Get<MyLocationTracker>();
                    msi.locationObtained += (object Jsender, MyLocationEventArgs je) =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(je.lat);
                    };
                    msi.ObtainMyLocation();
                }

            }

                locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;
                var position =  locator.GetPositionAsync(timeoutMilliseconds: 100000);



                BetaLat = position.Latitude;
                BetaLog = position.Longitude;

string str = string.Format("https://forecast.io/?mobile=1#/f/Lat:{0} , Long: {1}", BetaLat, BetaLog);


  var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();

 client.BaseAddress = new Uri(str);
```

---

Comment: thank you very much for your answer i tried your example however in the xamrian forms code I need to be able to genarte a url like this: https://forecast.io/?mobile=1#/f/"latitude"+","+"longitude" any idea how to do that based on the code you gave me? thanks again :)

Comment: I tried your updated code and get this error: 'Task<Position>' does not contain a definition for 'Longitude' and no extension method 'Longitude' accepting a first argument of type 'Task<Position>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue with this plugin not requesting permission at runtime even though it was shown on the Droid properties page.
The fix was to copy and paste this line into the manifest.xml file manually.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
```

For some reason Xamarin was not updating this line to include the targetSdkVersion when setting in the properties page.

Hope this helps someone as I spent hours trying to figure this out!

Answer (score 0):

The Xam.Plugin.Geolocator plugin created by JamesMontemagno has a great example of how to do this.

Here is how to get permission to use GPS - [Permission implementation example](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin/blob/master/samples/GeolocatorSample/GeolocatorSample/Utils.cs)

And here is a sample of how to implement it (including checking whether the GPS is on) - [GPS implementation example](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin/blob/master/samples/GeolocatorSample/GeolocatorSample/HomePage.xaml.cs)

Read the Readme.md for more system specific actions needed