# Geo Locator in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, geolocation, xamarin.forms

I am working on android application using xamarin forms. here is my code that is used to get latitude and Longitude. But when i am trying with Emulator it worked every time, but with mobile device sometimes works or sometimes not. please help me.

```
            var locator = Geolocator.Plugin.CrossGeolocator.Current;
            locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;

            try
            {
                var locator2 = Geolocator.Plugin.CrossGeolocator.Current;
                locator2.DesiredAccuracy = 50;

                var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(timeoutMilliseconds: 10000);

                if (position == null)
                {

                    return;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
```

Comment: I have tried to get the Latitude and Longitude in hall every time i did not get the location, but when i tried out side of hall Latitude and Longitude was getting appear. Is anybody have any solution for this problem?

Comment: Try this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39210048/how-to-prompt-user-for-geolocation-using-xamrian-forms

Comment: These permissions: ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION already enabled.

Answer (score 0):

on this page https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/maps_and_location/location/ you can see

Note: Setting ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION implies access to both coarse and fine location data. You should never have to set both permissions, only the minimal permission your app requires to work.

Answer (score 0):

add this inside android MainActiviy OnCreate()

```
Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = this;
```

add this to android mainactivity:

```
public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
{
    Plugin.Permissions.PermissionsImplementation.Current.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

then this code will function, prompting user for location permission.

```
                var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
                locator.DesiredAccuracy = 1000;
                var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(timeoutMilliseconds: 10000);
```

refer to:

https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/GeolocatorPlugin/