# Location permission for Android above 6.0 with Xamarin.Forms.Maps

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm trying to implement a Xamarin.Forms application using Xamarin.Forms.Maps, however I always fall into the exception:

Java.Lang.SecurityException: my location requires permission ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

I have already tried following the steps in this tutorial https://blog.xamarin.com/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow/ but did not get results.

Would anyone have something more consistent to help me?

What I'm intending is to use an application very close to Uber and I can not progress if I can not get the location permissions.

My MainPage looks like this in my PCL:

```
public partial class MainPage: ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
            var map = new Map ()
            {
                MapType = MapType.Street,
                IsShowingUser = true
            };

            var stack = new StackLayout {Spacing = 0};
            stack.Children.Add (map);

            Content = stack;
        }
    }
```

My MainActivity class in Xamarin.Android looks like this:

```
[Activity (Label = "ExampleGeolocation", Icon = "@ drawable / icon",
              Theme = "@ style / MainTheme", MainLauncher = true,
              ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]

    public class MainActivity: global :: Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity, ActivityCompat.IOnRequestPermissionsResultCallback
    {
        View layout;
        const int RequestLocationId = 0;
        readonly string [] PermissionsLocation = {Manifest.Permission.AccessCoarseLocation, Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation};

        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            global :: Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init (this, bundle);
            global :: Xamarin.FormsMaps.Init (this, bundle);

            Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = this;

            SetStatusBarColor (Android.Graphics.Color.Black);
            LoadApplication (new App ());
        }

        public override async void OnRequestPermissionsResult (int requestCode, string [] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Permission [] grantResults)
        {
            switch (requestCode)
            {
                case RequestLocationId:
                    {
                        if (grantResults [0] == Permission.Granted)
                        {
                            var snack = Snackbar.Make (layout, "Location Permission is Available.", Snackbar.LengthShort);
                            snack.Show ();

                            await GetLocationAsync ();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var snack = Snackbar.Make (layout, "Location Permission Denied", Snackbar.LengthShort);
                            snack.Show ();
                        }
                    }

                    break;
            }
        }

        async Task TryGetLocationAsync ()
        {
            if ((int) Build.VERSION.SdkInt <23)
            {
                await GetLocationAsync ();
                return;
            }

            await GetLocationPermissionAsync ();
        }

        async Task GetLocationPermissionAsync ()
        {
            const string permission = Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation;

            if (CheckSelfPermission (permission) == Permission.Granted)
            {
                await GetLocationAsync ();
                return;
            }

            if (ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale (permission))
            {
                Snackbar.Make (layout, "You must allow the application to access your location options.", Snackbar.LengthIndefinite)
                        .SetAction ("OK", v => RequestPermissions (PermissionsLocation, RequestLocationId))
                        .Show();

                return;
            }

            RequestPermissions (PermissionsLocation, RequestLocationId);
        }

        async Task GetLocationAsync ()
        {
            try
            {
                var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.ToString ();
                throw new NotImplementedException ();
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Did u add the permissions to the manifest? Also at what point in your code is the exception being thrown?

Comment: Also, when you write "I ... did not get results", what do you mean? 
Do you get the permission dialog? Which return code do you get from CheckSelfPermission ? Please provide more infomration

Comment: The code for calling the map when I use the IsShowingUser property = true

Comment: Here is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IWdpzpFChUQ

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Location permission for Android above 6.0 with Xamarin.Forms.Maps

You wrote a lot of code about permission but I can't find where you request the permission, you need request the permission before you use it.

When you set `IsShowingUser` property to true, you should request the permission first, here are three solutions.

## Solution 1:

I notice that you are using [PermissionsPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin) in your code, if you need request this permission in `PCL`, you could refer to the [PermissionsPlugin official sample](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin/tree/master/samples/PermissionsSample).

Add this code in your `MainActivity`:

```
public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Permission[] grantResults)
{
    PermissionsImplementation.Current.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

Request permission when you need it:

```
try
{
    var status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Location);
    if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
    {
        if(await CrossPermissions.Current.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationaleAsync(Permission.Location))
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Need location", "Gunna need that location", "OK");
        }

        var results = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(Permission.Location);
        status = results[Permission.Location];
     }

     if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
     {
         //Permission granted, do what you want do.
     }
     else if(status != PermissionStatus.Unknown)
     {
         await DisplayAlert("Location Denied", "Can not continue, try again.", "OK");
     }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //...
}
```

## Solution 2:

When you open your application, request the permission first, in `MainActivity` `OnStart` method:

```
protected override void OnStart()
{
    base.OnStart();

    if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, permission) != Permission.Granted)
    {
        ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new String[] { Manifest.Permission.AccessCoarseLocation, Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation }, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Permission Granted!!!");
    }
}
```

## Solution 3:

Use [DependencyService](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/) to request the permission when you need it, here is the [sample](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MarshmallowSamples/blob/master/RuntimePermissions/MarshmallowPermission/MainActivity.cs) related to the [tutorial](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MarshmallowSamples/blob/master/RuntimePermissions/MarshmallowPermission/MainActivity.cs) you have read. In this example, it requests permission when execute this line:

```
buttonGetLocation.Click += async (sender, e) => await TryGetLocationAsync();
```

Comment: solution 2: "permission" parameter is not defined in ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, permission)

Answer (score 5):

add this inside android MainActiviy OnCreate()

```
Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = this;
```

add this to android mainactivity:

```
public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
{
    Plugin.Permissions.PermissionsImplementation.Current.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

then this code will function, prompting user for location permission.

```
                var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
                locator.DesiredAccuracy = 1000;
                var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(timeoutMilliseconds: 10000);
```

refer to:

https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/GeolocatorPlugin/

Comment: what about iOS??

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you have set all necessary permissions. If you want to use `Xamarin.Forms.Maps` on Android be sure that you have the following permissions set in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file of your project:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

You can also set the permissions by clicking with the right mouse on your Android Project and selecting `Properties`. Go to the tab `Android Manifest` and mark all necessary permissions.

Be also sure that you have added the following two Statements in the application tag:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="ADD_YOUR_KEY_HERE" />
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```