# How can I get GPS Location of my device in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, geolocation, xamarin.essentials

I want to get the Longitude and Latitude of my device when the entry box named **entLocation** is **focused**. I am using **Xamarin.Essential Geolocation** to get the GPS location of my device I followed the documentation and tutorials and still I am unable to get the GPS Location. I have added permission below to my android manifest still nothing. I am getting an display alert on **"Error3"**, **Error3** is the exception when **Unable to get location**.

> The error is "**Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.Activity.requestPermissions(java.lang.String[],int)' on a null object reference**"

My questions:
1. What is my error in my code?
2. Can I get my gps location offline? If yes, how can I achieve that?

> uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"
>   uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
>   uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false" 
>   uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false"
>   uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="false"

```
private async void entLocation_FocusedAsync(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var request = new GeolocationRequest(GeolocationAccuracy.Medium);
            var location = await Geolocation.GetLocationAsync(request);

            if (location != null)
            {
                entLocation.Text = location.Longitude.ToString() + "," + location.Latitude.ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (FeatureNotSupportedException fnsEx)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Error1", fnsEx.ToString(), "ok");
        }
        catch (PermissionException pEx)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Error2", pEx.ToString(), "ok");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Error3", ex.ToString(), "ok");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also working on my first Xamarin project that requires location permissions. A couple of things you should try that may help you get GPS location.

#### My suggestions

**1)** You need to grant additional permissions in `AndroidManifest` file. These are

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

**2)** Since **Android 6.0 or above**, you need to have **runtime permissions**. To acchieve that, you need to override `OnStart()` method in your `MainActivity.cs`. I referenced to [Location permission for Android above 6.0 with Xamarin.Forms.Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48487333/location-permission-for-android-above-6-0-with-xamarin-forms-maps). Here is what I did

```
protected override void OnStart()
{
    base.OnStart();
    if(CheckSelfPermission(Manifest.Permission.AccessCoarseLocation) != (int)Permission.Granted)
    {
        RequestPermissions(new string[] { Manifest.Permission.AccessCoarseLocation, Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation }, 0);
    }

}
```

> **Important:** My solution here is just temporarily handle granting permissions. Visual Studio would show an exception when you build and run the project first time. After you choose **"allow"** from **"Allow access location?"** prompt on the device, you would not get the exception when run the project again. I have not handled this issue yet.

#### My limits

As I said, the problem isn't completely solved. My answer is to help you temporarily  solve location permissions issue and move on. And I don't know how to get location offline.

Comment: Does getting GPS location needs internet connection?

Comment: It may. GPS can also be identified via cellular provider or wifi connection. you can read **location provider** in this [Location Services] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/maps-and-location/location)

Comment: It is working with or without internet connection. I can get my GPS Location

Comment: Hi @Fuong, did u solve the first time launch apps ask for lcoation permission and crash problem?