# Geolocator plugin for xamarin forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, geolocation

I'm trying to develop a mobile app using Xamarin forms and part of this app is  get GPS location of users.

But when I run the app I get this exception message

> This functionality is not implemented in the portable version of this assembly.  You should reference the NuGet package from your main application project in order to reference the platform-specific implementation.

I tried to find a solution but nothing useful. Any suggestions please ?

I added this permissions to the android app:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

#### Code

```
try
{
    var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
    locator.DesiredAccuracy = 100;
    var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20), null, true);
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(exception.Message);
    // throw;
}
```

Comment: Can you create a new Hello World project that has the same exception and commit it on Github? Then, anyone can pull the project from Github and try possible solutions if needed.

Comment: ok i'll do it now and give you the link.

Comment: this is the link on github :https://github.com/pentest30/Commuter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Possible Solution

According to the [author's documentations](https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/GeolocatorPlugin/GettingStarted.html), you need to install [Current Activity Plugin for Xamarin.Android](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CurrentActivityPlugin/blob/master/README.md). And have following line of code in your `MainActivity.cs`.

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        // some code
        CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, bundle);
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
```

Because your demo project is running on **.Net 4.5**, I could not try it out. You can read the author's documenations carefully and try it again.

#### My Recommendation

I have looked at the Github page [GeolocatorPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin) that you are using. The author states that:

> The time is now with Xamarin.Essentials, which offers over 30 cross-platform native APIs in a single optimized package. I worked on this new library with an amazing team of developers and I highly highly highly recommend you check it out

So you should switch to use **Xamarin.essentials** plugin instead. Here is [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/geolocation?tabs=android) from Microsoft how to use **Geolocation** from that plugin.

I've also answered a similar question, you may need to reference to [how can I get gps location of my device in xamarin forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51868291/how-can-i-get-gps-location-of-my-device-in-xamarin-forms/51869899#51869899)

Comment: after several attempts i updated the xamarin.Forms to latest version and update all nuget packages .

Answer (score 1):

after several attempts i solved the problem by updating the xamarin.Forms to the latest version with the rest of  nuget packages.